# Nividia Temprature in 13.10 so high

Tags: 13.10, nvidia, xorg, 14.04, temperature

i had prpblem with the laptop tempreature with ubuntu 13.10  and Nvidia card NVS500M

after searching i found i can add the following line to the xorg.conf

`Option "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x2222;PowerMizerLevel=0x2; PowerMizerDefault=0x2; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x2"`

it solved the issue for the temprature but applications starts to crash in randome way

so i removed the xorg.conf and restarted the Laptop and found every thing back to normal and the temprature also ..

so my question is , is there another safer way to control the powermizer of Nividai to usethe low level of performance but without crashing any thing

Comment: cab some one help , i have upgraded to the 14.04 and the same issue still exists